# Subdomains not resolving in AWS Route 53

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, amazon-route53

I am trying to setup custom URLs for our Google Apps account at a new company (let's call it `mycompany.com`).  The domain for the business is registered via AWS Route 53 and I have setup a public hosted zone for the MX records on the top level domain (all which work fine).

My problem comes when I try to add CNAME sub-domains like `mail.mycompany.com` with the value `ghs.googlehosted.com`.

When I do this and try to test the DNS using `nslookup mail.mycompany.com` all I get in response is:

```
Server:     192.168.3.1
Address:    192.168.3.1#53

** server can't find mail.mycompany.com: NXDOMAIN
```

Any ideas why this would be the case or how to resolve the issue?

Comment: A common misconfigurationI see people make with Route 53 is redundant entry of domain parts, and the easiest way to check if this is the problem would be `dig mail.example.com.example.com`.  If that gives you a result, I'll explain further, if needed .

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thank you for the tip, as it turned out, the NS setting for the Hosted Zone did not match the NS servers for the registered domain.  This let to all manner of confusion.  I have fixed this issue, now I'm waiting for it to propagate to test it.  According to Amazon, this could take over 48hrs.